# Gradle erro app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android

Estou com um erro ao tentar gerar APK no Android Studio, esta sendo 
demonstrado a seguinte mensagem:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict.
```

Já realizei algumas mudanças com base nas informações que encontrei na web porém sem sucesso.

Grato.

Comment: bom aparentemente você está utilizando diferentes versões do googleservices. Isso ocorre comigo com o uso de libs adicionadas manualmente(adicionando o .jar no projeto)

Answer (score 0):

entra na build.gradle que se encontra aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e coloque as informações dessa maneira:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.naobemaocaso.com"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 12
    versionName "2.0"

    //para atualizar a versao do app  basta mudar o version code
    //version name não precisa alterar   mas e ele que e exibido na play store
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')
}
espero ter ajudado